# python class variables and instance variables

Tags: python

When I run the following code, it will output `20 13`, but why? I thought it should be `13 13`.

```py
class Example(object):
    sum = 10

example = Example()
Example.sum = 20
example.sum = 13
print(Example.sum, example.sum)
```

Comment: What is `example` ? Seems it's never defined

Comment: Because Example is not the same as example.

Comment: Please explain your question

Comment: You should have got the error - `NameError: name 'example' is not defined`

Comment: assuming example is an Example class object...the answer is because theyre not the same thing..Example is a class, example is a class object

Comment: Sorry for missing one line `example = Example()`, I have changed the code.

Comment: you are calling the class itself with this line `Example.sum`, if you want to return both print sum values to be 13 each, you need to create an instance of the class (of that object) like how you did for `example = Example()`

Comment: why do you think `example.sum = 13` should affect `Example.sum`? When you set an attribute, it always works on *the instance*.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `example.sum = 13`, you are setting the `sum` in that particular instance of the class `Example` (object) to 13, whereas setting `Example.sum = 20` sets the attribute of the class `Example` to 20, thus they will output different values.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where we create object first approach giver 20,13 and second approach giver 20,20

```
# first approach
class Example(object):
    sum = 10


Example.sum = 20
# create object
example = Example()
example.sum = 13

print(Example.sum, example.sum)

# second approach
# create object
example = Example()
example.sum = 13
Example.sum = 20


print(Example.sum, example.sum)
```

Comment: The second approch will output 20, 13 in my interpreter...